# the correct exception for my program

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the error "Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body."
I think I should use another exception, but can't think of which. The goal of the program is to read in a file, and add movie objects to inventory, as a RomCom or Action movie. However, I also need to manage exceptions.

```
Inventory inv = new Inventory();

        // TODO:  Read in the input file and populate the movieList. Manage exceptions.
        // On a failed movie load print the message
        // "Exception " + e.getMessage() + " for film " + title. No loading."
        FileReader file = new FileReader("src/movies_db.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String [] splitline = line.split("-");
            if (splitline[6]== null){// has as many parameters as an action movie
                //try {// try adding to action
                try{
                    inv.add(new Action(splitline[0], Integer.parseInt(splitline[1]), Integer.parseInt(splitline[2]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(splitline[3]), Integer.parseInt(splitline[5])));

                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Exception " + e.getMessage() + " for film " + splitline[0]+ " No loading.");
                }
            } // if loop
            else{
                try {// try adding to RomCom
                    inv.add(new RomCom(splitline[0], Integer.parseInt(splitline[1]), Integer.parseInt(splitline[2]), 
                            Integer.parseInt(splitline[3]), Integer.parseInt(splitline[5]), Integer.parseInt(splitline[6])));
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Exception " + e.getMessage() + " for film " + splitline[0]+ "No loading.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's because IOException is actually checking if inv.add() will possibly throw an IOException, and since it doesn't, it complains. In an event like this, I would say to simply catch an Exception. You can do some type checking if you want, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for `NumberFormatException`:

```
Integer.parseInt(String)
```

> Throws:
>       `NumberFormatException` - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

(from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)))

If the constructors `Action()` or `RomCom()`, or the method `inv.add()` can throw any exceptions, you should probably catch those too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a robust IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, you should be able to click on any methods in the try block and if you hover over it, the Javadoc should appear, listing any exceptions the method throws.